# Error on translating my web application

Tags: jquery, ajax, client-side, microsoft-translator

The code I used and the error I am getting (screenshot attached)

```html
<div onclick="event.stopPropagation();" id="translaterWidget"></div>
```

```js
var ts = document.getElementById("translaterWidget");
ts.innerHTML = '<div id="MicrosoftTranslatorWidget"></div>';

ts.style.display = 'block';

setTimeout(function() {
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.charset = "UTF-8";
  s.src = ((location && location.href && location.href.indexOf('https') == 0) ? "https://ssl.microsofttranslator.com" : "http://www.microsofttranslator.com") + "/ajax/v2/widget.aspx?mode=auto&from=en&layout=ts";
  var p = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement;
  p.insertBefore(s, p.firstChild);
}, 0);
```

Error

> _mste3("TranslateApiException: IP is over the quota: ID=0642.V2_Json.TranslateArray.16B1A559");

Comment: The error message seems to be quite clear: your IP Address exceeded the maximum translation quota (the maximum number of translations you are allowed to do per period of time from your machine). At first glance, this does not seem to be a programming issue.

Comment: Change the text for "enter image description here" link. add some meaningful there

Comment: The MS Translator API is rate-limited based on the number of characters you translate per hour. You are obviously exceeding this limit. You either need to restrict your usage, or pay for a higher service tier. See their Limits FAQ for more details: https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1147546-api-translator-text-limits

Comment: my code was working earlier, only recently i am facing this error ,even for a simple web page i am getting the same error .

Comment: my code was working earlier, only recently i am facing this error ,even for a simple web page i am getting the same error . i have in-cooperated the V3 version and getting the same

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your response.But my issue is,when i am making a request containing 2000 characters either by one or multiple requests
,its able to translate the whole.But when i am making a request of characters more than 2000 then it throws above error.Can please suggest any work around to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Translator Web Widget is being deprecated. Consider using only the Translator Text API or the [Webpage Translator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/web.aspx). There is no charge to use Webpage Translator and there's a Translator Text API subscription in the Azure portal that you can subscribe to for monthly use up to 2 million characters at no charge.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your response.But my issue is,when i am making a request containing 2000 characters either by one or multiple requests
,its able to translate the whole.But when i am making a request of characters more than 2000 then it throws above error.Can please suggest any work around to overcome this.